# dnf update with nobest option

Tags: yum, update, dnf

I've got following error during update:

> Error:
> Problem: cannot install the best update candidate for package glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-167.el8.x86_64
>
> - nothing provides glibc-common = 2.28-181.el8 needed by glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-181.el8.x86_64
> - nothing provides glibc(x86-64) = 2.28-181.el8 needed by glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-181.el8.x86_64
>   (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

It's caused by our staging system (katello) which does not yet provide that package for this stage. The "--no-best" option would let me update the system.

How can I estimate in such cases which effects will have this way of updating to my systems and how can I decide wheter to provide this package or to simply use "--nobest" at any time?

Answer (score 0):

I'd blame the staging repo. Ideally, the repo will always be in a consistent state, so that the latest versions of all packages can be installed at the same time without conflicts.

Therefore, the ideal solution would be to aim to achieve that state.

Meanwhile, updating with "--no-best" seems reasonable to me. It might be useful to try without "--no-best" first, and log the particular failures that happened, to keep track of the staging repo inconsistencies.